# NSMutableOrderedSet for To-Many Relationship in Subclass

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

When Xcode creates a managed subclass with a to-many relationship, it types the relationship member of the class as `NSSet`, like this:

```
class SomeObject: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var member: String

    @NSManaged var anotherOne: Int

    @NSManaged var relatedEntities: NSSet

}
```

Which makes creating new related entities somewhat arduous as I am forced to create a mutable buffer, as in:

```
let buffer = NSMutableSet(set: someObject.relatedEntities)
buffer.addObject(newRelatedEntity)
someObject.relatedEntities = NSSet(set: buffer)
```

My question: Is it safe to change the type of the `relatedEntities` member to `NSMutaleSet`, eg:

```
@NSManaged var relatedEntities:
```

for access to the `addObjects` method, or will this create problems in the context/model/anything?

Edit:

Also, would it be okay to just use

```
@NSManaged var relatedEntities: [RelatedEntity]
```

Comment: you can always call `- mutableSetValueForKey:`... see Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/mutableSetValueForKey:

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. Is it okay to set the type to `NSMutableSet` and use the `addObjects` method to interact with the data model?

Comment: I assume - but I don't know - it is not safe to override since most methods of NSManagedObject aren't. You know there should be convenience methods for adding objects to sets . At least in obj-c you can call something like addRelatedEntitiy: -see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437122/how-does-coredata-manage-class-relationship-creation

Comment: Is this a many-to-many relationship, or one-to-many?